# Error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python-3.x, database-connection, teradata

I'm trying to set up a connection between Python 3.7 and Teradata SQL Assistant. Below is the code I'm using, but I'm getting the following error... "InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'). Any idea why I'm getting this error?

```
import pyodbc
print ('Connecting to Teradata')
tdta_cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='xxx',UID='xxx',PWD='xxx')
tdta_cursor = tdta_cnxn.cursor()
print ('Success!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run into this szenario based on which ODBC drivers you have. Sometimes it can happen, that ODBC is not shure which drive to take. 
So you have to point it to this by just adding "Driver=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10" or "Driver={Teradata}" (or what your driver is) to the connection parameters.

As an alternative you can connect via native Python driver teradatasql (https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/).